# JQGrid Group Text Custom Formatter with Button inside and passing RowData

Tags: jqgrid

I have a requirement to provide a button on a grouped row , when onclick of that button , I should capture rowData. I've tried to implement this with custom formatter , grid.SetCell option, but didn't work. 
Here is Sample code:

```
grid.jqGrid({

        datatype: 'local',

colNames: ['Id', 'Order Id', 'Name', 'OrderName'],

 colModel : [

{ name: 'ID', index: 'ID', editable: true}, //// I grouped by this column

 { name: 'OrderID', index: 'OrderID', width: 30, align: 'center'},

 { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 30, align: 'center'},

 { name: 'OrderName', index: 'OrderName', width: 30, align: 'center'}

],

groupingView: {

            groupField: ['ID'],
            groupCollapse: true,
            groupColumnShow: [false],
            groupText: ['<b>{0}</b></div><input type = "button" class = "button" value = "NEW" id = "btnNew" style = "width:100px; hieght:10px" onclick = "javascript:AddNew({OrderID})" /><<b>{1} Orders</b>']


function AddNew(orderId)
{
//// DO SOME THING
}
```

In above example my grid will be grouped by Id , on each grouped row I need to create a button which onclick event  should consist of Order Id. (Order Id is same for all the rows under each group). I need to show Count here also.

I was not able to pass order Id in group Text above, then I use custom formatter on ID column like this .

```
var html ;

formatter: function(cellValue, options, rowObject)
{
 if ((options.rowId.toString()).indexOf("listghead") === -1) {

    html = cellvalue + "<input type = "button", value = "New" onclick = AddNew(' +rowObject[1] +')
}

return html;

}
```

rowObject value has been passed but grouping was broken. If I don't use the above if condition grouping works fine,  but onclick event is breaking.

Help me .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: hi did u find any solution for this?? i have same case

Answer (score 0):

You can get the row value through rowObject so:

```
html = rowObject.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].wholeText;
```

This code return a string with the content of rowObject to that columm

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the rowObject when it comes to group header , and it is not undefined or null when it comes to groupheader.

Just test it using alert(rowObject) when you detect it's group header.